# ajax multiple input form validation using java servlet not working. Ajax not displaying error

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

Ajax not working. This is my form. ajax not validating my server side code. As per the below code it is not showing the error .

```
<form id="postMveForm" action="movieDetails">

<input type="text" name="mvetitle" id="mveTitleId"><br/>
<div id="errormvetitle"></div><br/>

<textarea name="mveDescription" id="mveDescrId" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br/>
<div id="errormveDescr"></div><br/>
```

My ajax validation is not working. I need error to appear below the textfield if user focus the field and leaves it as an empty field.  No error showing when I focus the textfield and leaves it empty. ajax not working.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mveTitleId').blur(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'movieDetails',
                data : {
                    mvetitle : $('#mveTitleId').val()
                },
                success : function(responseText) {
                    $('#errormvetitle').text(responseText);
                }
            });
        });


        $('#mveDescrId').blur(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'movieDetails',
                data : {
                    mveDescription : $('#mveDescrId').val()
                },
                success : function(responseText) {
                    $('#errormveDescr').text(responseText);
                }
            });
        });     

    });    
    </script>
```

This the movieDetails servlet class.

```
      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

         {

           String mveTitle = request.getParameter("mvetitle");
            String mveDescrptn = request.getParameter("mveDescription");

        if(mveTitle.length()==0)    

                {
                    String mveTitleError = "Error movie Title field is Empty";

                    response.setContentType("text/plain");
                     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    response.getWriter().write(mveTitleError);           

                }                                     
                    if(mveDescrptn.length()==0)
                  {
                    String mveDescrptnError = "Error movie Description is empty";

                    response.setContentType("text/plain");
                     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    response.getWriter().write(mveDescrptnError);
                  }

              else {
              response.getWriter().append("success ").append(request.getContextPath());
                   }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

please check null on if conditionn.
if(mveTitle == null)   instead of  if(mveTitle.length()==0)
and if(mveDescrptn == null) instead of if(mveDescrptn.length()==0)

Comment: no error!! ajax not working. I can't understand where it is.

Comment: You can log to javascript using console.log. and make sure the request reach the backend server, put some log to java server example System.out.println("starting"). And url : 'movieDetails'. Fill the complete url example : http://localhost:8000/moviedetail